# How to search full name in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, search, codeigniter-4

My database table structure is as follows.

```
 -------------------------------
| id | f_name | m_name | l_name |
 -------------------------------
```

This is my model that I used to get results.

```php
    public function getContactInfo($start,$perpage) //  Swapnil
    {
        $keyword= $this->input->get('keyword'); // vishal
    
        $this->db->like(array('colleges_fname'=>$keyword)); // vishal
        $this->db->limit($perpage,$start);
    
        $result = $this->db->get("colleges");
    
        if($result->num_rows()>0) {
            return $result->result();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This is my view.

```html
<form class="form-inline ml-3" type="get" action="<?php echo base_url('clerk/collegestudent/view')?>">
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm ">
        <input class="form-control form-control-navbar" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" name="keyword">
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-navbar" type="submit">
                <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Currently it searches for the first name only. How to improve my code to search both first name and last name at a time?

Answer (score 2):

```
    public function getContactInfo($start,$perpage) //  Swapnil
    {
        $keyword= $this->input->get('keyword'); // vishal
        
        $this->db->group_start();
        $this->db->like('f_name', $keyword, 'after'); 
        $this->db->or_like('l_name', $keyword, 'after');
        $this->db->group_end();
        $this->db->limit($perpage,$start);
    
        $result = $this->db->get("colleges");
    
        if($result->num_rows()>0) {
            return $result->result();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The lines from group start to group end will reproduce something like:

```
(f_name LIKE "string%" OR l_name LIKE "string%")
```

If you want to search in both directions remove the third param in the like statements.

Comment: Then you're adding something else into the query, because this is how you search in both firstname and lastname at the same time for the same patterns

Comment: if it worked for you then please accept it so others can trust it and save their searching time

Comment: @M.Hemant it search only first name. I am not able to search full name at one time . What I do for search full name. Pls see my table structure.

Comment: Like I said, you might want to search in both directions. If that's the case you need to add the % to the both ends of your string.